# Publish to Greengrass Topic using API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-iot-greengrass

How do I go about creating an Api gateway on AWS for AWS Greengrass? I want to be able to publish to Topics through API using 3rd party applications

Answer (score 0):

Iot Publish can publish messages to MQTT Topic through IOT Core endpoint
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/apireference/API_iotdata_Publish.html

**Your API can use AWS SDK to invoke Iot Publish**

- [AWS SDK for .NET](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/goto/DotNetSDKV3/iot-data-2015-05-28/Publish)
- [AWS SDK for C++](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/goto/SdkForCpp/iot-data-2015-05-28/Publish)
- [AWS SDK for Go](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/goto/SdkForGoV1/iot-data-2015-05-28/Publish)
- [AWS SDK for Java V2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/goto/SdkForJavaV2/iot-data-2015-05-28/Publish)
- [AWS SDK for JavaScript](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/goto/AWSJavaScriptSDK/iot-data-2015-05-28/Publish)
- [AWS SDK for PHP V3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/goto/SdkForPHPV3/iot-data-2015-05-28/Publish)
- [AWS SDK for Python](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/goto/boto3/iot-data-2015-05-28/Publish)
- [AWS SDK for Ruby V3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/goto/SdkForRubyV3/iot-data-2015-05-28/Publish)

**IAM Permission required to invoke Iot Publish**

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "IOTAccess",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iot:Publish"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:123456789012:topic/topicName"
        ]
    }
]
}
```